# Select polygons (A) that contain polygons (B) by using R code

Tags: polygon, r

I am wondering how to select polygons (A) that contain polygons (B) by using R code.

```
B<-readOGR(dsn="H:/AP", layer="WWTP")
A<-readOGR(dsn="H:/AP", layer="catchment")
```

Comment: Welcome to gis.stackexchange! Please note that a good question on this site is expected to show some degree of research on your part, i.e. what you have tried and - if applicable - code so far. For more info, you can check our [faq].

Answer (score 3):

In the future please provide information on what you have already tried and a reproducible example. Whereas this Q&A site is a great resource we are not a coding service.

The rgeos library provides functions for overlay/intersection analysis. There are i[mportant nuances](http://lin-ear-th-inking.blogspot.com/2007/06/subtleties-of-ogc-covers-spatial.html) in the type of function (covers, within, contains) that is appropriate here. There is a big difference between having a polygon boundary entirely within another polygon, intersecting polygons (creating new polygon topologies) or having any concordance between polygons. Because your question is vague, I cannot provide a specific solution to your problem. However, here is a quick example of returning a Boolean (that can be used to select/subset polygons) using rgeos::gContains

```
library(rgeos)
library(sp)
p1 <- readWKT("POLYGON((0 0,0 2,1 3.5,3 3,4 1,3 0,0 0))", id=1)
  p1 <- SpatialPolygonsDataFrame(p1, data.frame(ID=1, row.names="1"))
p2 <- readWKT("POLYGON((4 4,4 6,5 7.5,7 7,8 5,7 4,4 4))", id=2)
  p2 <- SpatialPolygonsDataFrame(p2, data.frame(ID=2, row.names="2"))

catchment <- rbind(p1, p2)
WWTP <- readWKT("POLYGON((1 1,1 2,2 2,2 1,1 1))")

plot(catchment)
plot(WWTP, col="blue", add=TRUE)

gContains(catchment, WWTP, byid=TRUE)
```